# Google Cloud BigTable : Update the column value

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I have the following BigTable structure for an example:

```
Table1 : column_family_1 : column_1 : value
```

The `value` here is a number let's say. This is managed by a dataflow and I want to update the value every time.

This value might be an amount and I want to update it every time user makes a purchase (to maintain total spent till date), so I am doing the following in purchase event listener dataflow (whenever a purchase event is encountered):

- Make a BigTable request to get the value by id
- Add the amount spent in new purchase to the one present in BigTable search response
- Make a `Put` request to update the value

Although this approach has some network latency, it seems to work. The scenario where this fails is, when there are multiple workers of a dataflow, user makes more than one purchase and the events go to multiple workers, e.g.:

- Worker 1 gets event 1, fetches the amount and adds the spent amount into it
- Worker 2 gets event 2, fetches the **old** amount and adds the spent amount into it
- Both workers make `Put` requests and they get overwritten

To prevent this, I am trying to make a request which just says in plain text, `add 10 to the spent amount value`. Is this something we can do in dataflow?

Comment: I understand the scenario and when/why it fails, but I do not understand how are you trying to prevent it. Could you rephrase or elaborate this part, please: "To prevent this, I am trying to make a request which just says in plain text, `add 10 to the spent amount value`. Is this something we can do in dataflow?"

Comment: @RubénC. I am trying to prevent it via upsert command, an SQL interpretation of it will be something like `UPDATE table SET amount = amount + <new_deposit> WHERE person_id = <person_id>;`So, instead of reading it, adding the value and writing it back, I am updating it by issuing increment or update command.

Answer (score 5):

Bigtable has the capability to `Increment` values.  You can see more details in the [protobuf documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/bigtable/v2/bigtable.proto#L83).

Idempotency plays an important role in understanding counters in Bigtable. 
 In Bigtable, the `Put`s are generally idempotent, which means that you can run them multiple times and always get the same result (`a=2` will produce the same result no matter how many times you run it). `Increment`s are not idempotent, since running them multiple times will produce different results (`a++`, `a++` has a different result than `a++`, `a++`, `a++`).

Transient failures may or may not perform the `Increment`.  It's never clear from the client-side if the `Increment` succeeds during those transient errors.

This `Increment` feature is complicated to build in Dataflow because of this idempotency.  Dataflow has a concept of "bundles" which is a set of actions that act as a unit of work.  Those bundles are retried for transient failures (you can read more about Dataflow transient failure retries [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/faq#how-are-java-exceptions-handled-in-cloud-dataflow)).  Dataflow treats that "bundle" as a unit, bug Cloud Bigtable has to treat each individual item in the "bundle" as a distinct transaction, since Cloud Bigtable does not support multi-row transactions.

Given the mismatch in the expected behavior of "bundles", Cloud Bigtable will not allow you to run `Increment`s via Dataflow.

The options you have deserve more documentation than what I can provide here, but I can provide some options at a high level:

1. Always use `Put` for any new event you find, and sum up the values on Reads.  You can also write another job that does periodic clean up of rows by creating a "transaction" that deletes all current values, and writes a new cell with the sum
2. Use [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) which listens to Pub/Sub events and performs `Increment`s.  Here's a [Cloud Bigtable example using Cloud Functions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/node/cloud-functions).  You can also perform a `Get`, perform the addition and do a `CheckAndMutate` with the algorithm you describe in your post (I personally would opt for `CheckAndMutate` for consistency, if I were to choose this option).
3. Use [`AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/blob/master/bigtable-dataflow-parent/bigtable-hbase-beam/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/beam/AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn.java) to write your own `DoFn` that performs `Increment`s, or `CheckAndMutate`, but with the understanding that this may cause data integrity problems.

If the system is large enough, option #1 is your most robust option, but comes at the cost of system complexity. If you don't want that complexity, the option #2 is your next best bet (although I would opt for `CheckAndMutate`).  If you don't care about having data integrity and need high throughput (like "page counts" or other telemetry where it's ok to be wrong a small fraction of the time), then option #3 is going to be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation. As far as our use case is concerned, we need both data integrity and high throughput. As per the first solution, if we do not write that clean up job and perform `sum` aggregation on reads, does it make the aggregation considerably slower as the size grows? On the other hand, can we use `Put` on the same rows but append the new cells?

Comment: Also, after having a look at your code here, do you think I should go ahead and use multiple ReadModifyWrite requests (with apache beam) across multiple dataflow worker threads?

Comment: Aggregation does indeed get slower as the size grows.  If you use a Put, make sure to set the timestamp so that you don't get duplicates.  Multiple ReadModifyWrite can potentially cause correct correctness problems.  If you're going to use ReadModifyWrite, then you probably need to use Cloud Functions.

Comment: we need to do a cross table transaction in this dataflow (not just cross `row`) and I guess Bigtable does not support that. In this case, can we not write our own piece of code that takes care of this, e.g. `if(row doesn't exist in raw table){aggregate();}insertIntoRawTable();`.
This way, it won't retry the aggregation if the bundle is retried and retrying the insert will overwrite the duplicate.

Comment: That will work for the first batch where the key exists, but not for subsequent events.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself very clear. Each event has it's own id and the append only table (raw table in my previous comment) will store events as is, with combination of event id and reverse timestamp as BT row key. Now, when an event arrives, I want to update the aggregate table only once. For any reason, if the event is received twice (from Pubsub or by bundle retry from dataflow), the above logic will make sure the aggregate table doesn't get updated twice. Adding the same row in source table won't make any difference.

Comment: That makes sense.  I would suggest using a single `checkAndMutate` for that logic, since that method can do a read and write to the same row transactionally.

Comment: Unfortunately that would be a bit difficult for us to do as we are dealing with two different tables here. Source table (for `raw` events) and aggregate table (for aggregated metrics).

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be the following:

- To have one append-only table with the individual events, and an aggregated table with the relevant key and values to aggregate by.
- Use `AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn` to do a `Put` insert into the append-only table.
- In a sequential stage in the same dataflow, window events during a reasonable short period (5 seconds?) to group by the aggregation key.
- In the next stage/s of that dataflow (or at this point it could even be routed to another dataflow, really), perform a range scan per grouped key in the append-only table, aggregate the values and do a `Put` insert into that aggregated table.

That way:

- Ensuring that the events are in Bigtable when a window is triggered after the `AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn`, a consistent aggregate can be obtained.
- In the unlikely circumstance of one window finishing after the next triggered window (with an old view of the aggregation), the trigger timestamp can be used to differentiate the latest version of the cells.
- The append-only table could also be used for other kind/level of aggregations that could be decided to do afterwards.
- The maintenance is relatively simple, as it would not need any periodic clean job.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try add each transaction updates as separate column, using timestamps as qualifies, so total amount spent is simply summing all the columns? Periodically you can compact the N columns into one timestamp and the update can be atomic.